# R language - Scraping data from source code of a URL

Tags: r

I want to extract one specific data of the source code of a list of URL. Let's take an example with [one URL](https://www.lastminute.com/hotels/city/hotels-in-Los-Angeles-CA-US).
In the source code, I want to extract the words after `pfDataConfig.page.section` in this case it is `hotels.geo.city.US.united-states.14652.los-angeles` as you can see in the picture :
[image]

I tried several things using the package rvest but  without conclusive results.  Please, do you have any advices on how to find a solution ?

Thanks you so much.

Comment: Show what you tried and describe exactly where you are getting stuck.

Comment: Welcome to SO! What have you tried? What about `rvest`? Are you sure that policy of the target site allows to scrape it?

Answer (score 0):

Just import line by line and do a grep.

```
# Reading line by line
mylines <- readLines("/path/to/file")

# Finding target line(s)
mytargetline <- mylines[grepl("pfDataConfig.page.section", mylines)]

# Stringsplit by "=" and extracting second element
mytarget <- unlist(strsplit(mytargetline, "="))[2]
```